# Is it possible to read excel files that are stored in a MySQL database using Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have excel files stored in a MySQL database. I now want to connect to the database and create dataframes from these files using Pandas/Python. Is this possible? When I connect to the database and fetch the information it just gives me the entries in text i.e.

```
try:
   cursor = cnx.cursor()
   cursor.execute("""
      select *  from ExcelFiles
   """)
   result = cursor.fetchall()
   print(result)
finally:
    cnx.close()
```

Output:

> (38, 'Game 1.xlsx', 9561,
>   'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
>   datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 22, 55, 52), 'uploads/Game 1.xlsx', '1',
>   2)

Comment: It looks like you have Excel filenames stored in the database, which is quite different from the actual files. What does `SHOW CREATE TABLE ExcelFiles` show? It looks like the file are sanely in uploads. Recommend keeping it that way.

Comment: @danblack This is what that shows ---  [('ExcelFiles', "CREATE TABLE `ExcelFiles` (\n  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n  `File_Name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,\n  `Size` int(11) NOT NULL,\n  `Type` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,\n  `Uploaded_On` datetime NOT NULL,\n  `Location` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,\n  `status` enum('1','0') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',\n  `UserID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,\n  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=50 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci")]

Comment: Edit into the question next time. My assumption in the first comment is confirmed.

Comment: I see what you mean though. My files are actually stored in the uploads directory of my other project. All that seems to be stored in the MySQL database is the information about each file so it can be pulled from the upload folder.